# Json Serialization from C# Enum to function/object name

Tags: c#, json

I need the following output

{hello = "world", test=aobjectname}

I have tried doing a `enum{aobjectname}` in c# and `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`

Anyone else with a good idea how I might get the wanted output. The stuff i tried gives either test=1 or test="aobjectname".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would not be valid JSON. String-values in JSON *have* to be in quotes. So `test:"aobjectname"` is the correct output, and no JSON serializer in the world will give you any output without those quotes.

JSON is a language. Languages have specifications. And the [JSON language specification](http://json.org/) states, that a JSON object follows this structure:

[image: Object structure]

It also states, that a string value follows this structure:

[image: String structure]

If you violate those principles, then you no longer have JSON, but something of your own making, which is *based* on JSON. Which, in rare cases, can be fine. But you do need to know the sacrifice you are making: This is a language of your own design, so you will need to supply all the tooling around that language, including, but not limited to: Serializers and deserializers, MIME types, validators, etc.

In short, your object should look like this:

```
{hello: "world", test: "aobjectname"}
```

or

```
{hello: "world", test: 1}
```

By the way, if you need to convert `"aobjectname"` back to the enum value, you can do this by using the [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/essfb559.aspx) method.